# How to handle uncommon numeric keyboards?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have an app that does some simple, specific math for a micro-audience of users (people employed by my company in my location with Android phones and the same job title as me.)

My main Activity has 3 EditText's which each have the following tag in the XML:

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

When the user focuses on these fields, they are given a keyboard with only numbers and math symbols. The only math symbols that produce output in the field are the "-" (minus sign; only works once, and only as the first character in the field) and the "." (decimal point; only works once.) This is exactly the behavior I want.

A new user approached me today because he could not enter the value he needed using his LG G2. The problem is the G2's numeric keyboard: it displays a 12-key numeric keypad. 9 of the keys are for the digits, one is blank, and one shows a ".", with a "-" above it. Apparently, you need to use the shift key to get to the minus sign, but there is no shift key! Long pressing does not work. The only workaround I found was to switch him to the AOSP keyboard. This solution is not ideal.

My question: Is the G2 keyboard broken, is my code missing something, or is there some trick to this particular keyboard we couldn't find?

Comment: Interesting problem and post but I'm voting to close/migrate because this is not really a programming question and better fit for http://SuperUser.com For example, with some phones the volume buttons become ctrl or shift keys when focus is on a text or numeric control.

Comment: See here for one example: http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid/25956-ctrl-key.html

Comment: Thanks for the link and for the advice. I will try to find the proper key combos on the L2. To be clear,  are you implying that there is no problem in the code? I will close the question  if that is the case.

Comment: I don't know if there's a problem with the code, or the design of the input controls. I'm suggesting that it's likely a device/platform-specific issue. Besides, even if there was a bug in the device's input controls you couldn't do anything about it except wait for a patch. Hmm, I just realized that you're probably talking about your code. The only way to test would be to accept all input types and run it on that device and doing your own field validation.